# text not visible after moving UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

```
float newY = 0;
CGRect buttonFrame;
for(int i=1; i<=countTabItems;i++){
    id item = [self viewWithTag:i];
    if([item isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        UIButton *button = item;
        [item release];
        NSLog(@"got %@", button.titleLabel.text);
        buttonFrame = button.frame;
        buttonFrame.size.height = self.frame.size.height/countTabItems;
        buttonFrame.size.width = self.frame.size.width;
        buttonFrame.origin.x = 0;
        buttonFrame.origin.y = newY;

        button.frame = buttonFrame;
        [button setTitle:@"TEST" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"%0.2f",newY);
        [button release];
        newY += frame.size.height/countTabItems;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what is problem with this code, please. I use this to move buttons from their original position after which the UIButton is not showing any Title (text) on it.

Answer (score 1):

`[self viewWithTag:i];` does not retain anything so the release of item object should not be there. The same goes for the release of the button object. Try to remove those two releases and see if it solves your problem.